# I need to make the links open in a new window php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Working with a Wordpress theme and currently the icons in the header open in the current window which will take traffic away from the site.  I would like them to open in a new window/tab.  I know `target="_blank"` will get the result I need, just not sure of the syntax.

```
foreach( $gdl_social_icon as $social_name => $social_icon ) {
    $social_link = get_option($social_icon['name']);
    if( !empty($social_link) ) {
        echo '<div class="social-icon"><a href="' . $social_link . ' ">' ;
        echo '<img src="' . $social_icon['url'] . '" alt="' . $social_name . '"/>';
        echo '</a></div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're after, all you need is

```
echo '...<a href="' . $social_link . ' " target="_blank">';
```

Comment: Thanks, just didn't know the syntax. Tried a couple things and got a server error.

Answer (score 1):

Replace 4 line:

```
echo '<div class="social-icon"><a target="_blank" href="' . $social_link . ' ">' ;
```